How do I stream data from On premise Oracle database to ADLS Gen2?
I have this requirement where I need to stream XML BLOBs from an on-premise Oracle database into ADLS Gen2 BLOB Container. I was able to get a self hosted VM, install Integration Run time & JRE, configure the IR using the keys, and tested the connectivity between the on-premise Oracle database and ADLS Gen2 using Azure Data Factory "Copy" Activity.
I have 2 questions -

Can Oracle triggers (like AFTER INSERT) initiate an external event?
Does Azure have any service that listens to this table and opens the stream active until the data flushes out?

Could anyone please help me how to achieve this?
Source is an Oracle table with 5 columns



SURROGATE_ID
NATURAL_KEY1
NATURAL_KEY2
XML_COL
LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP




1
AAA
XYZ
xml BLOB
2024-04-08 12:03:34


2
AAB
XYX
xml BLOB
2024-04-08 12:03:39


3
AAC
XYZ
xml BLOB
2024-04-08 12:05:27



I need the XML_COL to be saved into the ADLS Gen 2 Blob container as separate XML files like below:
1_AAA_XYZ_20240408120334.xml
2_AAB_XYX_20240408120339.xml
3_AAC_XYZ_20240408120527.xml

Thanks
LN

Try the following:

Create an AFTER INSERT trigger on your Oracle table to initiate an external event (e.g., call a script or notify a service).
Implement an Azure Function or Azure Logic App to periodically query the Oracle table for new records.
Configure the Azure Function or Logic App to trigger an Azure Data Factory pipeline upon detecting new records.
Define an Azure Data Factory pipeline with a Copy Activity to stream XML BLOBs from Oracle to ADLS Gen2 Blob Container.
Use dynamic file naming in the Copy Activity to name the XML files in ADLS Gen2 Blob Container based on the data from the Oracle table.


I agree to your points but is there a solution that does not involve azure functions?

If you don't want to use Azure Functions or logic Apps, you can write a script (Python, PowerShell, etc.) or set up a scheduled task (using cron on Linux or Task Scheduler on Windows) to periodically check for new records in the Oracle table.
